# Uncheck random checkbox after alert

Tags: jquery

Some of you helped me before.
The question was to get a alertbox after all the 3 checkboxes were clicked but it seems there has to be a extra detail.
When the third checkbox is clicked, there has to be a alert and 1 of the checkboxes have to be unchecked(or all).

Now i've trying to modify my old script but i couldn't get it to work.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('input:checkbox').change(
function(){
    if (jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').length == jQuery('input:checkbox').length){
        alert('Alert Text.');
     --> Last Line  jQuery('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
    }
});
});
```

I've put the last line in myself but it didn't work same as some other options i've tried.
Could you help me solve this little problem?

Thanx already

Answer (score 0):

replace this with your --> Last Line

```
jQuery('input:checkbox').attr('checked',false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in place of the "last line":

```
jQuery('input:checkbox').attr('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in last line to uncheck last selected check box

```
jQuery(this).attr('checked', false);
```

Full code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

jQuery('input:checkbox').change(
function(){

    if (jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').length == jQuery('input:checkbox').length){

        alert('Alert Text.');
    jQuery(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
});
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gchoken/sEMUL/)

Comment: Thanx a lot! All of you had the same answer and i'm happy again:)